# simple view function in solidity

Tags: solidity

i just want to check whether the address is whitelisted or not that is set in the whiteLister function.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

contract minter{
    function whiteLister( address _user) public{
    }

    function checkWhhiteListed(address user) public view returns (bool){
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mapping to keep track of the address which is whitelisted or not..

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract minter{

  mapping(address => bool) whiteList;

  function whiteLister( address _user) public{
    // whiteList the given address
    whiteList[_user] = true;
  }

  function checkWhhiteListed(address user) public view returns (bool){
    // return whether given address is whitelisted or not
    return whiteList[user];
  }

}
```

Comment: Also i want to make an addition to that answer. In solidity all variables start with their default value at the beginning. So for that mapping the initial value for all addresses will be false.

Answer (score 0):

thank you.

i have found a solution.

i go like this...

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0 pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract minter{

  mapping(address => bool) public whiteList;

  function whiteLister( address _user) public{
    // whiteList the given address
    whiteList[_user] = true;
```

```
}
```